# How to send data to sidebar?

Tags: sidebar

I have a sql database of historical events, I would like it to post data into the sidebar area of a wordpress site. As I am very new to it I do not have any idea how to proceed. I would be thankful if anyone could help me out. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `sidebar.php` (or any `sidebar-xxx.php` file, depends on your theme) and interface with your database using the [wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

If your historical events are in the same DB as wordpress you can use the wpdb class straight away, if they are in another DB you can instanciate a new wpdb class with :

```
$my_db = new wpdb('user','pass','dbname','host');
```

Comment: You don't actually need the $wpdb global in that case.

Comment: @scribu, oops, updated.